# Need to use Codeigniter Class with core php

Tags: php, codeigniter

For long enough I have been using codeignter , its classes are really good,easy and useful.
I am trying to integrate **Pagination class** in my custom php framework, found in /base/system/libraries folder of CI setup, before I have successfully integrated Table class to create dynamic tables with php data in my frmework.
Here I am facing problem with `$CI =& get_instance();` in /base/system/libraries/Pagination.php, which gets instantiate in controller.php .
And its throwing error because I am not using whole controller , but just its classes.
Is there any solution by which I can use Pagination class , without get_instance().

Comment: You seem to have the whole concept of using codeigniter libraries upside down. Can you post some code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: If that's your _modus operandi_, you are better off using Zend Framework maybe.What do you mean "I'm not using controller anywhere"? So you just took CI's pagination class in your personal project, without the rest of the framework?

Comment: @JosephSilber , Yes i know its weird way to use it ;-) , but I am just including class file.And using its function by creating object.I am using CI's table class as following : `include_once(LIB_DIR.'/Table.php');$table = new Table('default_template');$table->set_heading($dataHeader);$table->generate(); ` etc

Comment: @DamienPirsy , I have edited question .You will understand now.

Comment: DOne.. Removed all the CI instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $CI =& get_instance();

    if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
        if ($CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment) != $base_page)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);

            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != $base_page)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }
    }
```

with

```
    if(isset($_GET['cur_page'])){
        $this->cur_page = $_GET['cur_page'];
    }else{
        $this->cur_page = 1;
    }
```

&

```
if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
        {
            $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp;'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
        }
        else
        {
            $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
        }
```

remove this.

Call it like ,

```
include_once(LIB_DIR.'/pagination.class.php');
$pagination = new Pagination();

$config['base_url'] = 'http://testme.com/stats.php?cur_page=';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20;

$pagination->initialize($config);

echo $pagination->create_links();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination class doesn't depend on the CI all that much. You can simply rewrite it a bit to find and replace all references to the "outside" with correct data it tries to allocate. Then Pagination will work without any interaction with the CI and you'll be able to use it in your framework.

Comment: Done.. Removed all the CI instances.